# OS X stuck on reboot updating to 10.13.4

Tags: macos, high-sierra, software-update

I have a Mid-2014 Macbook Pro I have tried to update to 10.13.4 from 10.13.3 a few times now, but everytime the result is the same: The update gets stuck after rebooting on the black screen with the progress bar.

- The bar gets stuck at about 75% after around 30 minutes
- I have let it be for many hours (overnight), no progress
- If I turn the computer off and on again, it gets stuck at the same place
- I seem to be unable to enter "safe mode" (holding down shift at power-on). I am however able to get into recovery mode.
- First I tried just using the App Store update; this has previously always worked for me.
- After restoring from time machine, I tried again, this time using the combo update. Same result.

**Questions**

1. I am back up and running now, having restored (yet again) from time machine, but still at 10.13.3. I'd still like to upgrade, but I don't know how to proceed. What are my options? "Re-install OS X" from recovery mode?
2. If it gets stuck on an update again (or some other time), how do I diagnose what it's stuck on next time? I see I can get to a terminal from recovery mode, but I don't know what logs to look in and what to look for - what's the way to better understand a stuck update?

Comment: Try reformatting your drive with disk utility in recovery mode, then reinstalling macOS 10.13.3. DO NOT put your TM backup back on.  Go through setup process and skip unnecessary steps. Create a user and go to the App Store and try to update. If it works, great! you can restore from your TM backup by using Migration Assistant, if same problem occurs reply here.

Comment: I'll keep that solution in mind, but I think I will try the less invasive option of re-installing on top if the existing installation first, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue some days ago with my mid 2015 MBPr. I ended up launching in recovery mode and reinstalled macOS. That fixed it for me.

I tried several other things like disk diagnosis and check disk in terminal but no luck.

Apparently this happens to a lot of people currently.